# How to link my .ejs file in my .html file

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs, nav

I have created two HTML files, index.html & contact.html.
I have a navigation bar where I can navigate from one HTML file to another.

I newly learnt to retrieve APIs and created an app.js and weather.ejs file.

1. How do I link my new weather.ejs file in the navigation bar? I tried to link it to views/weather.ejs but it says file not found. Please help!
2. From the navigation bar in my weather.ejs file, the links to index.html and contact.html no longer work! Any advice on what I need to change to allow me to navigate from my weather.ejx file, to my index.html and contact.html pages?

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">R.</a>

<button
  class="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
>
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="views/weather.ejs">Weather</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating express routes to serve these files as they will need to be rendered before being served up to the client. HTML is also valid as an ejs file so I would updated the extensions and place them all within a `views` folder.

Example structure:

```
- routes
----- index.js
- views
----- index.ejs
----- contact.ejs
----- weather.ejs
- package.json
- app.js
```

app.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Use Router
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

routes/index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index');
});
/* GET contact page. */
router.get('/contact', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('contact');
});
/* GET weather page. */
router.get('/weather', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('weather');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Navbar

```html
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/weather">Weather</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```